# FreeSwitch - how do i parse and take action using python?

Tags: python, linux, asterisk, freeswitch

I have this dial plan and i want to handle the dialed number using python. But its not working any idea?

default.xml (dialplan):

```
<extension name="Run Python">
  <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(?:\+|00)(\d+)$">
    <action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_number=${caller_id_number}"/>
    <action application="python" data="a" />    
 </condition>
</extension>
```

a.py (main dialing number router):

```
import freeswitch
def handler(session, args):
    consoleLog("INFO", "print this please >>>>>>>>>>>>>>!>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>!>")
```

***Not working, when call is made:***

```
2013-09-13 22:55:49.645980 [NOTICE] mod_python.c:212 Invoking py module: a
2013-09-13 22:55:49.645980 [DEBUG] mod_python.c:281 Call python script 
2013-09-13 22:55:49.645980 [DEBUG] mod_python.c:284 Finished calling python script 
2013-09-13 22:55:49.645980 [ERR] mod_python.c:293 Error calling python script
2013-09-13 22:55:49.645980 [ERR] mod_python.c:164 Python Error by calling script "a": <type 'exceptions.NameError'>
Message: global name 'consoleLog' is not defined
Exception: None

Traceback (most recent call last)
    File: "/usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/a.py", line 3, in handler
```

Comment: I think that  error message is rather self-explanatory: global name 'consoleLog' is not defined. It is used in handler but is never imported or defined.

Comment: http://wiki.freeswitch.org/index.php?title=Mod_python&redirect=no#.27consoleLog.27.2C_argument_2_of_type_.27char_.2A.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is telling you what the problem is: there's no such thing as `consoleLog`. Is this something defined in the `freeswitch` module? If so, you want`freeswitch.consoleLog`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
freeswitch.consoleLog("info","your debug string")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
session.execute("log", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
```